Next.js serverless API won't update data automatically until I redeploy the project
When I POST something through the API, the data stores in the database successfully. However, my GET API doesn't retrieve the updated data and instead shows the old data that was available at build time. Even after deleting the data from the MongoDB database, it still shows the previous data that no longer exists.
When I'm running it locally with the local API (localhost:3000/blogs/api), it works as expected, updating and deleting the data properly. But after deploying to Vercel, the deployed API (vercel.app/blogs/api) causes this issue.
This is my GET API route:
import { connectDB } from "@/lib/connectDB";

export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    // connect to the database
    const db = await connectDB();

    // get all the blogs data from the database
    const blogs = await db.collection("blogs").find().toArray();
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(blogs), {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, max-age=0",
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "Error fetching blogs", error }),
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};

This is how I'm fetching the data:
  // fetch the blogs data
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/blogs/api`, {
    cache: "no-store",
    next: {
      revalidate: 0,
    },
  });

So far, I added export const dynamic = "force-dynamic" in the Homepage to fetch fresh data. I also set the prop next: {revalidate: 0} to fetch data instantly. Finally, I added this header to the API route
 headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, max-age=0",
      },

I expected these to force the GET API to retrieve updated data, but it still returns the old data until I redeploy.
